# Removing French words from database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a Ecommerce database where the company is providing support in different countries (France and UK). But the company focuses mainly in UK and has a data warehouse which they dump the data from Magento.

In a few tables like PRODUCTS and all some French wordings are listed. I need to avoid it and make complete data to be available in English.

How can I remove the existing French wordings (there might be many tables and many columns) from the database and replace it with English?

Do you have any suggestions on which how this can be done?

Comment: most than probably, it can't be done. If you had "normal" words and know which products are spelled in french, then you might use a dictionary table to make a translation. But for products names, wording are rarely "normal", you wont find the right translation in a dictionary for most of the cases, and you will just screw your data.

Comment: Well, you could narrow it down a lot by looking for words that are **not** english, and then manually processing the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The french words are coming from Magento products and category tables, Have filtered the values where "**STORE_ID=0**" , This will take only the global values.